# Bash not expanding some variables

Tags: bash

I am storing some commands in an array.Bellow is a simplified example

```
#!/bin/bash
test_arr=()
x="mural.png"
for q in 10 12 14; do
  for i in 4 6 8; do
    test_arr+=("$x_$q_$i")
  done
done
echo "${test_arr[@]}"

unset test_arr
for q in 10 12 14; do
  for i in 4 6 8; do
    test_arr+=("$x"_"$q"_"$i")
  done
done
echo "${test_arr[@]}"
```

Output:

```
4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8
4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8 test_stack.png_10_4 test_stack.png_10_6 test_stack.png_10_8 test_stack.png_12_4 test_stack.png_12_6 test_stack.png_12_8 test_stack.png_14_4 test_stack.png_14_6 test_stack.png_14_8
```

The following gives the correct output

```
#!/bin/bash
test_arr=()
x="mural.png"
#for q in 10 12 14; do
#  for i in 4 6 8; do
#    test_arr+=("$x_$q_$i")
#  done
#done
#echo "${test_arr[@]}"

unset test_arr
for q in 10 12 14; do
  for i in 4 6 8; do
    test_arr+=("$x"_"$q"_"$i")
  done
done
echo "${test_arr[@]}"
```

Output:

```
mural.png_10_4 mural.png_10_6 mural.png_10_8 mural.png_12_4 mural.png_12_6 mural.png_12_8 mural.png_14_4 mural.png_14_6 mural.png_14_8
```

Why does the variables get expanded  when using `"$x"_"$q"_"$i"` and not  `"$x_$q_$i"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"_" is a valid character for variable names.

```
"${x}_${q}_$i"
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need loops; `bash` can do the expansion for you

```
$ echo mural.png_{10,12,14}_{4,6,8}

mural.png_10_4 mural.png_10_6 mural.png_10_8 mural....
```